# Travelling with expensive jewelries gift from my princess employer

Tags: customs-and-immigration, philippines, import-taxes

[image][image][image][image]

Im worried  because one of my relative from philippines told me i cant go home with this expensive jewelries that my employer gave me because she love that i work good for her.  She told me that philippine airport will question me because of this.

Comment: You may be taking a risk even posting the photos here. Do you need all the boxes? Jewelry gets stolen from checked in luggage regularly I believe. The security ppl tell the handlers where it is. It looks like too much to carry on your person, so maybe Fedex or something is better.

Comment: Ok if you intend to take all of this one go, it sure is going to raise some red flag at the customs. Unless you are a filthy rich celebrity, the customs would surely like to know the origin of all this. I seriously doubt they will believe your 
 employer gifted you all of this.

Comment: What's the total value of all this?  It's impossible to tell pretty costume jewelry (worth 5 or 10 bucks a piece - like Coco Chanel would wear) from retail "gem" jewelry (which can have a retail value of 100s or 1000s of dollars) (but can be resold for very little), in a photo.  What's it all worth ?!

Answer (score 7):

Per Philippine customs regulations, returning contract workers who have been overseas for over 6 months can bring back "used personal effects up to value of PHP 10,000.-" duty free. Since this is only about US$200, it is *highly* likely that your jewelry is worth more than this, and **you will need to pay large Customs duties** and potentially also face interrogation about where you acquired all this.  In addition, traveling with valuable jewelry like this on your person seems quite risky: you will definitely not want to put it in checked luggage!

Unless you are planning on keeping all the jewelry, I would strongly suggest **you sell off the pieces you don't need and transfer the money back to the Philippines instead**.  Alternatively, you can also bring back up to US$10000 cash without declaring it, although this too is quite risky.

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ph-philippines-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm